# Expired objects do not delete from s3 bucket, been months

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I set expiration dates on objects through the API. It's now May and many of these objects expired in March. All the docs say expired objects will be wiped on a daily basis but I think something is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expires` metadata field is used to control caching of objects in browsers and CDNs. It is not related to actually deleting objects from Amazon S3.

If you wish to automatically delete objects from Amazon S3 after a certain period of time, you should crate a Lifecycle Rule.

See: [Object Lifecycle Management - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)